# Can you make google sheet's 'OR' exit early in the event of an early match?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a conditional format that requires around 23 'OR' options. How can I make it only run on cells with text in them, and then also exit early as soon as ONE match is found.
Here is the conditional format code:

```
=IF(OR(
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Action"),($K$3=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Adventure"),($K$4=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Animation"),($K$5=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Comedy"),($K$6=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Crime"),($K$6=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Drama"),($K$7=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Family"),($K$8=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Fantasy"),($K$9=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Historical"),($K$10=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Horror"),($K$11=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Medical"),($K$12=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Musical"),($K$13=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Paranormal"),($K$14=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Romance"),($K$15=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Sci-Fi"),($K$16=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Sport"),($K$17=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Spy"),($K$18=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Superhero"),($K$19=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Thriller"),($K$20=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "War"),($K$21=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Western"),($K$22=TRUE)),
AND(REGEXMATCH($F2, "Zombie"),($K$23=TRUE))),
1, 0)
```

Since it runs on a fair few cells, making it exit early, or optimising in some way, would be incredibly helpful. Thanks for any help you can provide.
I have tried putting an AND before the or, with the extra condition of NOT(ISBLANK(cell)) but it still runs the OR checks anyway (hence long processing time)

Edit:more information

Comment: It'll automatically exit early. Checking for other conditions after a true is found would be redundant.

Comment: @Frogglet, you'll always get the best answers and solutions if you share a copy of your sheet, being sure to set permissions to "Anyone with the link can edit." For instance, as I look at your formula, it's massively redundant. It could probably be written in one short line given the correct setup. But without access to your sheet, there's no way of knowing. Do consider sharing a link.

Comment: I also think your K references are off, since Comedy and Crime both reference K6. It seems your pattern is 1:1, so Comedy should reference K6 and Crime should reference K7, etc.—meaning everything in your formula from Crime down would be off.

Comment: Yeah the K references was an error I corrected quite quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your most recent comments, Frogglet, it occurred to me that my previous short CF formula will work with genres in one column given a little modification. Personally, I still think six columns is less prone to error and easier to add to; but if you want to keep the setup you have:

```
=ArrayFormula(($A2<>"")*(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT($F2,","))),MATCH(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT($F2,","))),FILTER($J$3:$J$50,$K$3:$K$50=TRUE),0))))>0))
```

I added a second sheet called "Erik 2" which implements this CF formula.

All I did was replace the previous six-column range with a TRANSPOSEd SPLIT of your single-column range.

In addition, this formula is "light," so it can be applied to the entire A2:F range instead of limiting and constantly changing the range to which CF is applied.

Comment: This works and achieves all my requirements. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Great. It actually pushed me to think of a new technique I hadn't used before, so thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Frogglet, see my comments above. But, for instance, just based on what I see in your formula and using a little creativity (assuming I'm right about the fact that your formula pairing both "Comedy" and "Crime" with $K$6 being a mistake, and therefore everything from there down being wrong), here's a much shorter formula that would accomplish the same thing:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("K"&SEARCH(LEFT($F2,3),"XXACTADVANICOMCRIDRAFAMFANHISHORMIDMUSPARROMSCISPOSPYSUPTHRWARWESZOM")/3+2)=TRUE,1,0))
```

I don't see why you'd be using REGEXMATCH at all.

What I did here was basically form a long string from the first three letters of each of your genres, bumping it in two with the "XX" up front so that every start of a genre-chunk is found at positions divisible by 3. Then I searched for the first three letters, found the location, divided by three and added 2 to offset to where your Column-K locations for TRUE start.

But in real life, if I could see your sheet, it would be even shorter by far; because we'd set up your genre list in a separate sheet as a reference, use it for validation in F2 and then INDEX(MATCH()) to get the right pairing with Column K.

Comment: I recommend that you make a copy of the sheet and share a link to the copy with full edit permissions. Then people here can work on the copy, and you can implement any working solutions yourself by copying them over to your original. This keeps you from having other names in the version history, while also allowing you the best chance of getting the kind of help you are requesting.

Comment: Here is an edit link to a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17z3pq_3zCNBa-3A8Yd3Pt1ejXmFKWHcHA_lwqneKfU4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Great. I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your sheet makes things clear, Frogglet.

I set up a new sheet called "Erik" in your sample spreadsheet. I changed the format so that your previous comma-separated list in F:F is broken up into columns F:K. These columns use Data Validation based on your complete genre-list column, which A.) makes it easy for you to select genres quickly and B.) assures you don't mistype anything. It also makes writing a CF formula much easier.

The CF custom formula I could now apply to A2:K is as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(($A2<>"")*(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(TRANSPOSE($F2:$K2),MATCH(TRANSPOSE($F2:$K2),FILTER($O$3:$O$50,$P$3:$P$50=TRUE),0))))>0))
```

Personally, I would have put your genre checklist in its own sheet. But it works fine as-is (as long as you only do your sorting on Columns A:K and not on entire rows).

Comment: I really appreciate the effort put into your solution, however I think I will stick to the old implementation and just limit the rows I run it on and manually increase as the list grows.
I chose this because your version requires seperated out genres, which would increase the size and make mobile viewing (main use) difficult
I also know for a fact the user's phone strongly forces spelling to be correct, hence typo's won't happen.

Thankyou again for all your help though.

Comment: Frogglet, you've already got spelling errors and other anomalies in your existing list. And mobile users will have to scroll right whether the genres take up one column or six, won't they? However, you know what you're trying to do with it better than I would, for sure. So go with what you think is best.

Comment: Actually, if you still want to use my shorter formula, Frogglet, it occurs to me that it will work with a simple modification. I added another sheet called Erik 2 with that solution in place; and I'll post another answer here.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=N(REGEXMATCH(F2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(J:J, K:K=TRUE))))
```

[image: 0]